How to umount a systemd-managed mount (snap) that refuses to stop
I'm trying to remove the Firefox snap from my system. snap remove fails with the following error:
➜  ~ sudo snap remove firefox
2024-10-17T21:19:24-04:00 ERROR cannot remove snap file "firefox", will retry in 3 mins: systemctl command [stop
snap-firefox-4848.mount] failed with exit status 1: stderr:
Job failed. See "journalctl -xe" for details.
2024-10-17T21:22:24-04:00 ERROR cannot remove snap file "firefox", will retry in 3 mins: umount: /snap/firefox/4848: not mounted.
Remove snap "firefox" (4848) from the system                                                                                                      -error: change finished in status "Undone" with no error message

systemctl status returns:
➜  ~ systemctl status snap-firefox-4848.mount
● snap-firefox-4848.mount - Mount unit for firefox, revision 4848
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/snap-firefox-4848.mount; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (mounted) (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2024-10-17 21:19:24 EDT; 3min 51s ago
      Where: /snap/firefox/4848
       What: /dev/loop3
      Tasks: 0 (limit: 19110)
     Memory: 16.0K
     CGroup: /system.slice/snap-firefox-4848.mount

Oct 17 21:19:02 BlackBox0 systemd[1]: Mounting snap-firefox-4848.mount - Mount unit for firefox, revision 4848...
Oct 17 21:19:02 BlackBox0 systemd[1]: Mounted snap-firefox-4848.mount - Mount unit for firefox, revision 4848.
Oct 17 21:19:24 BlackBox0 systemd[1]: Unmounting snap-firefox-4848.mount - Mount unit for firefox, revision 4848...
Oct 17 21:19:24 BlackBox0 umount[957]: umount: /snap/firefox/4848: not mounted.
Oct 17 21:19:24 BlackBox0 systemd[1]: snap-firefox-4848.mount: Mount process exited, code=exited, status=32/n/a
Oct 17 21:19:24 BlackBox0 systemd[1]: Failed unmounting snap-firefox-4848.mount - Mount unit for firefox, revision 4848.

systemctl stop returns:
➜  ~ sudo systemctl stop snap-firefox-4848.mount
Job failed. See "journalctl -xe" for details.

journalctl -xe after trying to stop the snap returns:
Oct 17 21:24:46 BlackBox0 sudo[1510]:      eon : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/eon ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/systemctl stop snap-firefox-4848.mount
Oct 17 21:24:46 BlackBox0 sudo[1510]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=1000)
Oct 17 21:24:46 BlackBox0 systemd[1]: Unmounting snap-firefox-4848.mount - Mount unit for firefox, revision 4848...
░░ Subject: A stop job for unit snap-firefox-4848.mount has begun execution
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░
░░ A stop job for unit snap-firefox-4848.mount has begun execution.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 1511.
Oct 17 21:24:46 BlackBox0 umount[1514]: umount: /snap/firefox/4848: not mounted.
Oct 17 21:24:46 BlackBox0 systemd[1]: snap-firefox-4848.mount: Mount process exited, code=exited, status=32/n/a
░░ Subject: Unit process exited
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░
░░ An n/a= process belonging to unit snap-firefox-4848.mount has exited.
░░
░░ The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 32.
Oct 17 21:24:46 BlackBox0 systemd[1]: Failed unmounting snap-firefox-4848.mount - Mount unit for firefox, revision 4848.
░░ Subject: A stop job for unit snap-firefox-4848.mount has finished
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░
░░ A stop job for unit snap-firefox-4848.mount has finished.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 1511 and the job result is failed.
Oct 17 21:24:46 BlackBox0 sudo[1510]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root

Any ideas as to how I could stop this?
Thanks!

Why have you tagged the question as being about a Ubuntu-Debian workflow issue?  or are you using Debian and that's why it was tagged?  Your question doesn't appear to be at related to Debian-Ubuntu packaging/workflows.
